# ScrollToTop after AJAX call

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, telerik, radajaxmanager

In a project we are using teleriks `RadAjaxManagerProxy` to send AJAX requests and I was delegated the easy task to implement a scroll-to-top-of-the-screen behaviour through javascript after an AJAX call. This was not at all as easy as expected.

Among other things, I have tried placing my javascript function directly on the page, I have worked with `RadAjaxManager.ResponseScript` and I have tested with jquery AJAX functions but still no progress. Does anybody have a good clue how to solve it?

This is my latest attempt and I did actually make it work if putting an alert into the code, like this:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, typeof(Page), "ScrollToTop", "alert('hello');", true);
```

But whenever I try to insert javascript code like `window.location = '#';` or `window.scrollTo(0,0);` it nevertheless doesn't scroll to top. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` is used only together with UpdatePanels, which I didn't use on my page. Instead I found a solution based on getting the actual `RadAjaxManagerProxy` for the page. This was done by using the function `GetCurrent()` on the MasterPage's `RadAjaxManager`. Hopefully this will save some hours for anyone else with the same problem! My solution:

```
RadAjaxManager.GetCurrent(Page).ResponseScripts.Add("window.scrollTo(0, 0);");
```